# Composer package being removed everytime I commit

Tags: git, codeigniter, azure, composer-php

I'm having this very weird issue that started to happen a few days ago.

I work in a websystem in my company that uses `Git` (which he host on BitBucket as a private repository) as its VCS, `CodeIgniter` as framework and `Composer` as package manager. It worked flawless for a long time, but when I added a dependency to Composer it started giving me trouble.

Now, everytime I commit, it simply removes this dependency from the server. This breaks many features that my system has, impacting a lot of people's work.

Because of this, now everytime I commit something new, I have to run a `composer update` on the server (which is an Azure Server, by the way). Nothing was changed either on Azure or on my code, except from the new required dependency.

I know that this is quite vague, but where can I start looking to find the source of this problem or what can I do about it (apart from running `composer update` everytime I commit something)?

Comment: Did you commit `composer.lock` after adding this dependency?

Comment: @rob006 well, if this can be the reason of it, you might have found the problem. Since this system is being worked by me and an colleage, he might've added composer.lock to .gitignore erranously. I'll remove it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rob006 said in a comment above, the problem was that `composer.lock` was not being commited to the server, it stayed only on my machine. I removed it from the project's `.gitignore` file, ran `composer update` again and since then I've had 0 problems.